# Tensorflow Lite crashing on Android (Samsung A13)

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow

we are running Tensorflow Lite via the C++ interface on Android and everything is working smoothly. But we discovered a problem with Tensorflow Lite when running the forwardPass on some Android Devices. One of the devices that can reproduce the crash reliably is the Samsung A13.
I have tried version 2.12.1 and 2.13 and the problem is still there
The problem occurs after running the inference multiple times for about 1 minute. The memory consumption seems stable.

Do you know where a good starting point would be to debug that issue?

We are trying to build an example app to reproduce the crash to better share our findings.

#### System information

- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Android 13
- **Mobile device (e.g. iPhone 8, Pixel 2, Samsung Galaxy) if the issue
  happens on a mobile device**: Samsung A13
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: source
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 2.12.1, 2.13
- **Python version**: 3.10.12
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: bazel 6.2.1-homebrew
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**: NDK 22

##### Crashlog

```
libabc.so (void tflite::ops::builtin::add::EvalAdd<(tflite::ops::builtin::add::KernelType)2>(TfLiteContext*, TfLiteNode*, TfLiteAddParams*, tflite::ops::builtin::add::OpData const*, TfLiteTensor const*, TfLiteTensor const*, TfLiteTensor*)+2588)
libabc.so (TfLiteStatus tflite::ops::builtin::add::Eval<(tflite::ops::builtin::add::KernelType)2>(TfLiteContext*, TfLiteNode*)+168)
libabc.so (tflite::impl::Subgraph::Invoke()+708)
libabc.so (tflite::impl::Interpreter::Invoke()+92)
```